# Find Multiple string in file using grep

Tags: linux, unix, grep, vi

How to find multiple strings in a file and its should return ***true*** when all the strings are present in a file using grep Linux.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please show sample data along with expected output and some effort you have done trying to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if grep -q string1 filename && grep -q string2 filename; then
  echo 'True'
else
 echo 'false'
fi
```

Test Snippet :

[image: Test Output]

Answer (score 1):

To search multile strings in a file you can use egrep or grep on linux.

```
egrep -ri --color 'string1|string2|string3' /path/to/file

-r search recursively
-i ignore case
--color - displays the search matches with color
```

You can do then and echo $? which will display 0 (true) if your grep matched anything and 1 (false) if the grep command had no matches

```
$? is a variable holding the return value of the last command you ran.
```

From here you can play with bash and create a small script or whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

One in awk. First the test file:

```
$ cat file
foo
bar
baz
```

Code and test run:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    RS="\177"                             # set something unusual to RS and append
    FS=FS "\n" }                          # \n to FS to make the whole file one record
{
    print (/foo/&&/bar/?"true":"false") } # search and output true or false
    # exit (/foo/&&/bar/?0:1)             # exit if you are interested in return value
' file
true
```

One-liner:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="\177";FS=FS "\n"} {print (/foo/&&/bar/?"true":"false")}' file
```